# Root height not taking full view height (React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So here i'm trying to set the root to dynamically take the full view height, i already set the `height` and `min-height` in `index.css` but it's not working. But when i tried to set the height using px unit, it works. I don't know what is wrong, i appreciate anyone who help me to find the solution :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have example code hosted anywhere like CodeSandbox, Codepen etc?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass height. You don't need min-height.

```
height: 100vh;
```